# Which download file should I use for setting up a node in Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: full-node, linux, raspberry-pi

I want to setup a node at home using Raspberry Pi 4. I am running 64-bit [Ubuntu server OS](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) on it. Which [monero download file](https://www.getmonero.org/downloads/#cli) should I pick, Linux ARMv8 or Linux ARMv7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Raspberry Pi's should generally be avoided for running a node as they don't have hardware AES, which means you'll have slower syncing/scanning/verification. There are many comparable devices which *do have* hardware AES, thus are better options.

Second, if you are definitely running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu (see `uname -a` to confirm) and are using a board the has hardware AES (which Raspberry Pi's don't), you can use the ARMv8 release.

Otherwise (and in your case) use the ARMv7 release. If you're really brave / patient (it takes a long time on Raspberry Pi's), [compile from source](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#on-the-raspberry-pi).

Comment: As I have reported in my other [question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/13268/12701), ARMv8 binaries do not run successfully on Raspberry Pi 4. I will probably try using ARMv7 release.