# How to resolve the "Illegal instruction (core dumped)" error on Raspberry Pi 4 using 64-bit Ubuntu server

Tags: full-node, linux, raspberry-pi

After following the [answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/13267/12701) to my previous question, I downloaded ARMv8 binaries to my Raspberry Pi 4 machine, running 64 bit Ubuntu server OS.

This is the `uname -a` output on the terminal:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-1042-raspi #46-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 30 00:35:40 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Now, running ARMv8 binary `monerod` on this machine results in following error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd monero-aarch64-linux-gnu-v0.17.2.0/
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/monero-aarch64-linux-gnu-v0.17.2.0$ ./monerod 
2021-08-28 19:28:06.458 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-release)
2021-08-28 19:28:06.458 I Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2021-08-28 19:28:06.458 I Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2021-08-28 19:28:06.459 I Initializing core...
2021-08-28 19:28:06.460 I Loading blockchain from folder /home/ubuntu/.bitmonero/lmdb ...
2021-08-28 19:28:06.460 W The blockchain is on a rotating drive: this will be very slow, use an SSD if possible
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/monero-aarch64-linux-gnu-v0.17.2.0$
```

How do I resolve this `Illegal instruction (core dumped)` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the ARMv7 release build. The Monero release build for ARMv8 is compiled for native AES support, which Raspberry Pi's simply don't have.

If you're really wedded to running the ARMv8 release, you *may* have luck exporting `MONERO_USE_SOFTWARE_AES=1` and `MONERO_RANDOMX_UMASK=8` before running.

Comment: How do I "export" `MONERO_USE_SOFTWARE_AES=1` and `MONERO_RANDOMX_UMASK=8`. And what do you mean by "before running"?

Comment: `export x=y` then run, or run like `x=y monerod`. Both achieve the same thing. Or just use the ARMv7 builds.

Comment: After giving export commands for these two parameters you mentioned on the bash shell, monerod still gives the same "Illegal instruction (core dumped)" error.